# Admob App status inactive iPhone

Tags: iphone, admob, coronasdk, reddot

I created two apps on admob for iPad and iPhone 4-5 days back. Ads are appearing for both devices but for iPhone the status is inactive. The status for iPad app turns to active after 1 day.I don't know why the status of iPhone app is still inactive and ads are still appearing for inactive app. I have created apps to work on corona sdk. Can anyone please help me?